# Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class :last

Tags: css

I am using HTML5 and CSS3 for my project. while validating my CSS using W3C  validator i am getting the following error, saying

**Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class :last**

```
.point:last {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

How do i fix this issue.

Comment: Without knowing your markup? Use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:last` doesn't exist.

Just `:last-child`, `:last-of-type`, `:nth-last-child` and `:nth-last-of-type`.

Comment: Ho wo remove that selecting one by default ?

Comment: @suresh: remove from where? CSS can't remove elements, use JS.

Comment: can you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963136/how-to-remove-radio-button-default-checked-in-zend

Answer (score 0):

:last is not an pseudo element, `:last-child` or :`nth:last-child` these are but :last child pseudo are not supported by older versions of IE so its always a better approach to use `:first-child` or `:nth-first-child` as it is a good practice.