# How to remove radio button default checked in zend

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

HI guys i am trying to remove the default checked value for **radio** button

**Here is my code:**

```
 <?php if ($this->isAllowed('order.customer.ticket-details')) : ?>
<fieldset class="order-obv-ticket">
    <legend><?php echo $this->translate('order_obv_ticket'); ?></legend>
    <div id="order-ticket-details"></div>
</fieldset>
<?php endif;?>
```

Here is my js function:

```
    function getOrderTicketDetails(orderId, contactId)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: vbdURL+'/order/customer/ticket-details',
            data:{orderId : orderId,
                  contactId :  contactId },
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(response){
                $('#order-ticket-details').html(response);
                if(null != order['requestTicketId']){
                    $("#ticketId-"+ order['requestTicketId']).prop('checked', true);
                } else {
                    if (0 < $("input[id^='ticketId-']").length) {
                        $("input[id^='ticketId-']:first").prop('checked', true);
                        order['requestTicketId'] = $("input[id^='ticketId-']:first").val();
                    } 
                }
            }
        });

}
```

Here is my radio button:

```
<span class="actions">
<input name="ticketId" id="ticketId-{{ticketId}}" type="radio" class="selectAll js-set-order-ticket" value="{{ticketId}}"/>
```

Can anyone help me how can i make default radio buttons should be unchecked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the radio button?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: @suresh: Eh? Just remove `$("input[id^='ticketId-']:first").prop('checked', true);`

Comment: instead of removing i just made it like false. the problem is before its not called my js file. now i got  to know.. problem solved

Comment: @panther can you please check this if you can answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968958/get-last-7-days-records-from-table-in-zend

Answer (score -1):

I Have solved my problem by chaging this line

```
$("input[id^='ticketId-']:first").prop('checked', true);
```

TO

```
$("input[id^='ticketId-']:first").prop('checked', false);
```