# Get last 7 days records from table in zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Hi guys i am trying to get last 7 days closed tickets from table
Here is the query i have wrote

```
'closed' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(IF(rt.assignee_id IS NOT NULL,IF(rt.status_id = 24,1,0),0))')
```

can any one help me how can i add my condition inside IF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: actually i need to get last 7 days count of records where status_id is 24..and in that query i have already written sum with status_id 24.. now i would like to add to get last 7 days records

Comment: Without seeing some sample data and expected output, words alone are not enough to express.

Comment: So do you want me to add images are sql query result

Comment: Images are generally **NO**. Please read the link I provided earlier; it will clarify on how to create a good question

Comment: Yeah i  understand your question..and if i want to add more related code it will take more code as we need to write code in multiple pages there is no code in one single page so thats the reason i have added one line so i thought that will be enought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'closed' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(IF(rt.assignee_id IS NOT NULL, IF(rt.status_id = 24, IF(created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY, 1,0),0),0))')`

not 100% sure about the `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY`, but i think you will understand it.

Comment: Okay let me check